# Need Xpath expression for selecting Create Task option please help me with this

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Need Xpath expression for selecting Create Task option please help me with this:

```
<ul class="container" style="padding-left:5%;padding-top:0.5%;padding-bottom:0.5%;">
<li id="createTask">
<a onclick="createTask();">
Create Task
</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to solve this using `xpath`, you may rely on the `li` tag and it's id:

```
//li[@id="createTask"]/a
```

Note that more explicit and reliable way would be to find the link by [Partial Link Text](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-partial-link-text). Example in java:

```
WebElement createLink = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Create Task"));
createLink.click();
```

Comment: @divya according to what you provided, it should. Are you sure the link is visible and not inside an iframe?

Comment: Are there more links with the same id and text on the page, including hidden ones? WebDriver will only interact with the first matching XPath, if it is a hidden one then an exception will be thrown. Also you may need to put a wait that checks for visibility before clicking the link.

Comment: @divya could you also throw a link to the web site you are interacting against and the current code you are running? Thanks.

Comment: It is calling a javascript function create task